# Difference between st_length() and st_m()

Tags: postgis-2.0

My question is about the differences between st_length() and st_m() in postgis.

The reason I ask this is because in a MultiLineString I can´t calculate st_m(), but I can st_length().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ST_M()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_M.html) returns the M coordinate of the point so is undefined on a MultiLineString. [ST_Length()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Length.html) returns the length of the line so is well defined for your MultiLineString (though would return 0 if you use a polygon).